# Proper use of constants in C

Tags: c

I just found a bug in my code which can be simplified to:

```
float c;
int a,b;
a=5;b=6;
c=(a+b)/2;
```

In my debugging c has the value 5, i.e. integer division was executed.

This leads me to the question: What is a good practice when using numbers that are not stored  in a variable, i.e. constant. In my case, the denominator 2.

When I'm implementing mathematical formulas that carry various constant like this, should I **always** put `.0` at the end to make sure its internally used as a `double`? Does it speed up the operating time of my program? How much extra work has to be done if a constant has to be converted from `int` to `double`?

formulas like

```
z = 180 * 3.1415 * x  + 5*y^2 - (10*x-y)/(y+x);
```

where `x`,`y`,`z` are doubles.

So my question is,

Is it "clean code" to write all factors with a `.0` at the end ? It does decrease readability of the code quite alot, especially if the formulas are very long. But with this convention, I would prevent errors like the one discribed at the beginning.

Comment: If you want a double, then yes, you have to make it a double.  No bartenders were harmed in the writing of this comment.

Comment: This is not a problem of using constants or not. Using constants or macro will never change performances, your compiler will probably generate the same binary code. Here, you need to use a double, constant or not. In general, magic numbers are discouraged, but 2 is commonly not considered as magic number.

Comment: If it is treated as double it gets converted either way, so there is no performance benifit in just writing `2` instead of `2.0`.

Comment: A period suffices; the zero in `.0` is not necessary.

Comment: @Amy  `I prefer using 2f over 2.0. This is just a preference though.` And your code **NEVER** compiles :D. It can be some kind of preference.

Answer (score 5):

Constants have a type at compile time, just as variables do.  If a numeric constant contains a decimal point and no type suffix then its type is `double`.  If it does not contain a decimal point and no suffix it will be one of the integer types (which one depends on the value of the constant and the range of the relevant types).  So there's no speedup or slowdown associated solely with the type of the constant.

When it comes to performing calculations, integer arithmetic tends to be faster than floating point, so as a rule don't use floating point values unless you need to.

Comment: Technically, a type suffix is not sufficient for a decimal floating constant. [There must be either a decimal point or an exponent part, or no deal, suffix notwithstanding](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2).  But I think it's a common extension to accept a digit sequence with suffix but no decimal point as a floating constant.

Comment: `When it comes to performing calculations, integer arithmetic tends to be faster than floating point` - disputable. For example ARM FPU has almost the same execution time. But scaling in many applications is not needed

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm implementing mathematical formulas that carry various constant like this, should I always put .0 at the end to make sure its internally used as a double ?

Only if you need to make sure the result is a `double`.  If you want an integer result, then don't append a `.0`.  If you want a `float` result, append `.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm implementing mathematical formulas that carry various
>   constant like this, should I always put .0 at the end to make sure its
>   internally used as a double ?

Where indeed you do intend your constants to have type `double`, then yes, you should use one of the forms for constants of that type.  Where those constants have a zero fractional part and are expressed without an exponent, appending `.0` is a good way to put them in such a form.

On the other hand, no, you should not blindly slap `.0` on all your constants.  Just as with variables, you need to pay attention to what type you want each constant to have.  Use a corresponding form.

> Does it speed up the operating time of
>   my program ?

The types of your constants may affect the *correctness* of your program, as indeed was your starting point.  Where that is the case, relative performance is irrelevant.  No matter how fast you do it, it does not help you to perform the wrong computation.  On the other hand, where the change from an integer constant to a floating constant does not affect the correctness of the computation, it is probably because the context in which the constant appears requires a conversion anyway.  In that event, it is likely that the compiler just inserts a constant of the converted type in the first place.  There is then no runtime performance impact.

> How much extra work has to be done if a constant has to
>   be converted from int to double ?

At runtime, generally none.  Both implicit and explicit conversions *of constants* will normally be performed at compile time, as discussed above.

> Is it "clean code" to write all factors with a ".0" at the end ?

If they are all meant to be `double`s? Yes, it's clean.  And it can keep you out of trouble if you otherwise have difficulty remembering to pay attention to the types of constants.

It does tend to feel a little overdone to me when I see code that meticulously uses floating constants with integer values in contexts where an implicit integer -> floating-point conversion would be performed anyway, but it's a valid choice that serves a reasonable purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way

```
float c;
int a,b;
a=5;b=6;
c=(float)(a+b)/2;
```

Just **cast** to whatever you expect it to be. Same goes with double. This way you avoid the trouble of adding .0f and other stuffs and the code remains clean (readable).

**float**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  double c;
  int a = 20,b = 3;
  c=(float)a/b;
  printf("c:%.10f\n",c);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> c:6.6666665077

**double**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  double c;
  int a = 20,b = 3;
  c=(double)a/b;
  printf("c:%.10f\n",c);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> c:6.6666666667